# Django translation inside templates: unable to recognize variables from context dictionary and object attributes

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to use Django translation and `{% translate %}` tag inside my template files. Wherever I have some hard coded strings, things work just fine. The problem, however, occurs when I try to translate text from object attributes sent to the templates inside context dictionary.

So I have a context dictionary like below:

```
context = {
   'object_list': <QuerySet[
                       <SiteDataKeyValue: some random text>, 
                       <SiteDataKeyValue: Some other random text>,
                       <SiteDataKeyValue: and some more random text>,
                  ],
}
```

And without translation, I access these objects very easily, for example:

```
<h1>how I access the value of the objects:</h1>
{% for object in object_list %}
<p>{{ object.value }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Now, I try to use `{% translate %}` tag according to [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/translation/#translate-template-tag), and I use the following syntax:

```
<h1>how I access the value of the objects:</h1>
{% for object in object_list %}
<p>{% translate object.value %} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

But after running `manage.py makemessages -l -i .venv` command, Django fails to recognize `{% translate object.value %}` and show NO error message. After some research, I even tried using `with` command to render the object value inside a variable, as below:

```
{% for object in object_list %}
{% with value=object.value %}
<p>{% translate value %} </p>
{% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

But again, no success.

What am I doing wrong? Can someone please help me on this?

Your answer and help is appreciated in advance.

UPDATE:

I tried using the following structure as well, as suggested by [dostogircse171](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3443037/dostogircse171), but still no success; `makemessages` command does not recognize this text inside my template.

```
{% for object in object_list %}
{% with value=object.value %}
<p>{{ value|trans }}</p>
{% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

I even tried using `{{ value|translate }}`, and nothing happened :(.

Comment: Your code seems all right apart from using <p>{% translate value %} </p> into the template loop. Instead use this with trans filter <p>{{ value|trans }} </p>

Comment: @dostogircse171 I'm using this tag according to django docs, but I will try your method and let you know the outcome. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @dostogircse171 I tried what you suggested, but still no success. any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you add "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware" middleware under settings.py file?

Comment: Yes I did actually, I've thought of another easier method to achieve my goal, and I'm going to add it as an asnswer. Thank you a lot for your answer.